# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. Parse.com

Tags: android, gradle, parse-platform

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 2

My project is not connecting with parse and i have followed all the steps given at parse.com docs. I have tried both new project and existing project to connect it with parse but it is not connecting.

Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 4s 824ms.

folloing is my existing project mainActivity.java onCreate code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    Parse.initialize(this, "8R4nAHgdPDJ422tuZyHNE2Hjp3F50y4pSlO9sA1b", "qJomEl0uICAsg7uwiDvxEtWlTWovb3S01N8a3XNr");


    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Following is the **gradle** code for dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

Following is the AndroidManifest.xml code for asking/checking about internet connection:

I have also included Parse-1.11.0.jar in my libs.

Comment: have you googled it?

Comment: yeah googled it and checked all the links and follow the instructions but still having same error

Comment: did you try writing your parse code after
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: yeah i have tried it but still found same error. following is the code which i wrote according to your opinion.

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        Parse.initialize(this, "8R4nAHgdPDJ422tuZyHNE2Hjp3F50y4pSlO9sA1b", "qJomEl0uICAsg7uwiDvxEtWlTWovb3S01N8a3XNr");


        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject.put("foo", "bar");
        testObject.saveInBackground();

Comment: put your build.gradle of module Gradle script

Comment: you want me to see the code of build.gradle?

Comment: yes!, put it on this thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this

```
android {...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
..}
```

and add `multiDexEnabled true` in `defaultConfig` tag

This is my Application Class `public class Example extends MultiDexApplication {`

in manifest add like this `<application
        android:name=".Example"`

and this is my gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true // add this
}
```

Comment: Where to add the code. Sorry i m new on android please guide me

Comment: in Gradle script of build.gradle [Module]

Comment: here is my code for build.gradle under app folder in project view

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }

Comment: defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sevenpmtryparse"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

Comment: compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.11.0.jar')
}
 you can see i have added your code but finding still error

Comment: where you add `multiDexEnable true`? add it in `defaultConfig {...}` tag and implement to your Application class

Comment: Now i found this error after following your upper instructions

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class

Comment: how to implement and where to implement

Comment: what would be the content for example class?

Comment: i have created example class and extends multidex but my class have no content. is it right?

Comment: it is okay, now can you run?

Comment: run it and found the following error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class

Comment: <code>android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    } <code>

Comment: defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sevenpmtryparse"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

Comment: compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.11.0.jar')
}

Comment: above is the gradle file

Comment: Fixed my problem by following your solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Remove the below line from your gradle file**

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

because you already have it here

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
```

**These lines as to be in a class extending Application**

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

Parse.initialize(this, "8R4nAHgdPDJ*****E2Hj0y4pSlO9sA1b", "qJomEl0uICAsg7uwiDvxEtW****3S01N8a3XNr");
```

And you shouldn't post these code, it's meant to be kept secret.

**For example here:**

```
package <your.package.name>;

import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;

public class ClassNameApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, "2zMz0hbE****r4sMwZJrYtX", "YdK7lFBh5MI6gca*****WPXmKb");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}

}
```

And add this class name in your manifest file:

**here**:

```
<application
    android:name=".ClassNameApplication "
    android:allowBackup="true"
    ......
```

Comment: you mean i have to make a new class which will extend my mainActivity.java class

Comment: package com.example.sevenpmtryparse;

import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;

public class KeyToParse extends Application{

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    Parse.initialize(this, "8R4nAHgdP**********2Hjp3F50y4pSlO9sA1b", "qJomEl0uICAsg7uwiDvxEt******************888a3XNr");

}

Comment: this is the code i have done but the class can not resolve initialize and enableLocalDatastore

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [Multidex](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Also you have some structure problems. The following lines should be called only once. So you need to create a class application and register it in manifest then call your lines onCreate in that application class.. Here is the [example.](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/).

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_KEY");
```

Good luck there.

Comment: I have made a new class and register it in Manifest file following is the code
<application>
        android:name=".KeyToParse"   <----------- This is class name which i made
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="xyz"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Comment: following is the code of my KeyToParse class
package com.example.sevenpmtryparse;

import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;

public class KeyToParse extends Application{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        Parse.initialize(this, "8R*****************************Hjp3F50y4pSlO9sA1b", "qJ*********************************1N8a3XNr");
    }
}

Comment: but still having problem

Comment: What is the problem you are getting? still exit with error code 2 or problem about parse?

Comment: Did you implement multidex?