# Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle when using eds payment gateway android sdk

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I'm getting error when run my project. This error come when i added eds payment gateway android sdk.

here my **build.gradle:-**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "visionfresh.android.catalyst.com.visionfresh"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/fluent-hc-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-win-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar')
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/ebs.jar')
    compile project(':EBS')
}
```

I am new in android developing please help me.This is my first project which i integrate payment gateway. Thanks in advance!

here my **logcat:-**

```
        Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
    :EBS:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:compileLint
    :EBS:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:checkReleaseManifest
    :EBS:prepareReleaseDependencies
    :EBS:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :EBS:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:checkDebugManifest
    :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComDaimajiaSliderLibrary115Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareVisionFreshEBSUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareDebugDependencies
    :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
    Information:BUILD FAILED
    Information:Total time: 1 mins 49.461 secs
    Information:1 error
    Information:0 warnings
    Information:See complete output in console
```

My **Manifest:-**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="visionfresh.android.catalyst.com.visionfresh">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
          <!--  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>  -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShopByCategory"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUp"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TrackListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SingleTrackActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProductsCategory"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FilterClass"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgetPassword"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProductsDetails"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Description"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutThisItem"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TouchOnImage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MyAccount"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WishList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ZoomLevel"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChangePassword"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AccountInformation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MyAddress"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Legal"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".InnnerInformation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Review"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Discount_Offer_View_All"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AnyOtherQuery"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FullScreenViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CheckOut"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SubCategory"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ItemDetails"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MyOrder"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OrderDetail"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ReturnProducts"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProceedToPay"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="@string/hostname"
                    android:scheme="com.merchantapp.testkit" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PaymentSuccessActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: what is name of `payment gateway sdk ` in here

Comment: Elaborate answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014193/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-parse-com/34014593#34014593

Comment: yes my payment gateway name is EBS.

Comment: @Survivor is not working for me its give me error `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/ebs/android/sdk/AppController.class`

Comment: you can exclude AppController

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable multi dex option in your project

```
   public class YouApplication extends Application {

   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
   }
```

}

after that update your gradile

```
   android {
   compileSdkVersion 22
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

edit this line in manifest in application tag

```
android:name="ypurpackage_name.youApplication"
```

Comment: when added your code to my project it's give error `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/ebs/android/sdk/AppController.class`

Comment: Thats mean use latest version of compile library

Comment: what is the latest version of compile libary.

Comment: @anna plz see edited code add new line in manifest inside application tag

Comment: if you got your solution then like my ans

Comment: what is fill in "youApplication"  name.

Comment: @anna you can add any name of this class

Comment: I added my class name but its give error `not assignable to android.app.Application`

Comment: I added MainActivity.java class.

Comment: you have created this class in your package   public class YouApplication extends Application {

   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
   }